# The app that I'm working on runs perfectly on the android studio emulator, but can't install on device

Tags: android-studio

The app that I'm working on works perfectly on android studio emulator but when it's installing on my device it says this:
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity

Answer (score 1):

Try gradle on the right => AppName => install => unistallAll  then after finishing => run the project

like you see on the screen below

[image]